# Bing Maps: how to set best zoom depending on search query

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

How to set best zoom level on Bing Maps depending on user search query using ajax API v7. For example if the search query is a city name - I need to set zoom level to show the whole city and if the query is an accurate address - I need to show this address, so the zoom level will be bigger. Just like it works here: https://www.bing.com/maps/

Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations does not help. It only centering the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by setting [ViewOptions.bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx) via [Microsoft.Maps.Map.setView method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx):

> `bounds`  [LocationRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx) *The bounding rectangle of the map view. If both*
>   *are specified, bounds takes precedence over center.*

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {

    var addresses = [
        "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA",
        "Helsinki, Finland",
        "Australia"
    ];


    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("myMap"),
        {
            credentials: "YOUR-BING-KEY",
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
        }
    );

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', {
        callback: function() {
            searchLocation(map, addresses[1],  //<- set address 
                function(geocodeResult, userData) {
                    map.setView({bounds:geocodeResult.results[0].bestView });
                },
                function(geocodeRequest) {
                    console.log('An error occured...');
                });

        }
    });
}


function searchLocation(map, query, success, error) {
    var searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
    var geocodeRequest = { where: query, count: 1, callback: success, errorCallback: error };
    searchManager.geocode(geocodeRequest);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap();">
    <div id="myMap" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! _bestView_ is the thing I was looking for.